# Decorator Pattern Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, decorator

This is an object-oriented design question that is specific to Spring Boot. I'm extending a Spring Boot application that has an interface that is being extended and used inside another service.  The interface uses dependency injection to choose the implementation.  I don't want to change that.  I think the inheritance design is nice for Spring Boot, but the interface does not give me the necessary methods for my implementation.  Do I am thinking the Decorator Pattern, and mixing in another interface.  The interface to be extended is...

```
public interface DataStrategyService {

    DataRecord getEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord);

    DataRecord getEntityByBK(DataRecord dataRecord);

    void overwriteEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord);

    void saveEntity(DataRecord dataRecord);

}
```

There is an implementation already that works already and makes sense with that interface like so...

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="data.strategy", havingValue="DataBase")
public class DataBaseDataStrategyService implements DataStrategyService {
        DataRecord getEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord{
          //implementation stuff
        }

        DataRecord getEntityByBK(DataRecord dataRecord){
          //implementation stuff
        }

        void overwriteEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord){
          //implementation stuff
        }

        void saveEntity(DataRecord dataRecord){
          //implementation stuff
        }
}
```

But that interface, it doesn't give me what I need for the implementation I'm doing, so Im going to mix in another Decorator like so...

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="data.strategy", havingValue="CASSANDRA")
public interface ColumnFamilyDataStrategyDecorator {
    Map<String, Object> insertEntity(DataRecord dataRecord);
    Map<String, Object> deleteEntity(DataRecord dataRecord);
}
```

And the concrete class that would be the class that would use the decorator is...

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="data.strategy", havingValue="CASSANDRA")
public class ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService implements DataStrategyService, ColumnFamilyDataStrategyDecorator {
  Map<String, Object> insertEntity(DataRecord dataRecord){
      //implementation
  }

  Map<String, Object> deleteEntity(DataRecord dataRecord){
      //implementation
  }

  DataRecord getEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord{
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService.getEntityByPK() currently not supported.");
  }

  DataRecord getEntityByBK(DataRecord dataRecord){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService.getEntityByBK() currently not supported.");
  }

  void overwriteEntityByPK(DataRecord dataRecord){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService.overwriteEntityByPK() currently not supported.");
  }

  void saveEntity(DataRecord dataRecord){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService.saveEntity() currently not supported.");
  }
}
```

As you can see there some `UnsupportedOperationException`s being thrown.  Looks a little messy.  However, I don't really want to use Adapter pattern with delegation because then I wouldn't be able to use the Spring dependency inject as the author intended.  But on other other hand, the exceptions look pretty messy.  Any recommendations?

Also: My intention is to use `ColumnFamilyDataStrategyDecorator` to have some new methods that could work to replace the other interface's methods. But, I don't want to touch the calling code if possible. I don't want to implement a design pattern if it is the wrong thing to do :). But this way, I can leave the calling code alone at least, as I do not own it. The thing is, the other interface's methods are still needed for the `DataBaseDataStrategyService` implementation. `DataBaseDataStrategyService` is using DataStrategyService and will continue to do so. And the service that has a property of DataStrategyService, aka the calling code, which will also be calling `ColumnFamilyDataStrategyService`, I also don't want to touch that calling code if I don't have to. This decorator pattern I basically touch as little code as possible.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Your interface seems designed for database interaction but you say it makes sense for a messaging platform (Kafka) but not a database (Cassandra).  How does this make sense for Kafka?  There's no 'primary key' in Kafka.

Comment: If my memory serves, we either can remove or update entries in the topics. These entries are inmutable.

Comment: Hi I took out Kafka from the name of any Class or method.  Actually I was trying to obfuscate the names of the methods because it is real code from a client.  I am not concerned as much with what the implementations are actually doing, just more of a design thing where I want to inherit from an interface that I can't implement, so that I can use dependcy injection